# ASP.NET adding a form to Master Page

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages

So I've never really coded a website using ASP.NET. I'm trying to add a search form to a masterpage for my site. The problem is the whole body is wrapped in a form tag, which makes the functionality of my new form non-existant. I have a habbit of making bad situations worse by messing around with things I don't yet understand. So I thought I'd ask for your advice, my thoughts were:

- Remove the runat="server" form tag completely.
- Close it before my form and replace it at the end of my form.
- Code within the button (which I later noticed you can't open.
- Give up on ASP.NET and go back to PHP lol.

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a by-design concept in ASP.NET to have just a single form for a page. You should implement search functionality within this single form.

Comment: But if you are going to use JSON and update searched entities asynchronously with javascript you can implement a method on you page marked with [WebMethod] attribute and call it using XmlHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised as I am used to hard coding in open source languages, that I was using HTML specific syntax, which was conflicting with the  tag surounding the whole masterpage. In using the tools on the side I found my solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Master page will be like this

```
  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
   CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </head>
  <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="bodycontent" runat="server">

           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
      </form>
  </body> 
  </html>
```

you can write the search page like this

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodycontent" Runat="Server">
      //dnt include form tag here having runat = server
   </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I wanted it on the masterpage, so I wouldn't have to manually put it in on each page. But I'm asuming this isn't possible? As I can't use form tags, should I just put some c# code behind the button to go to a results page, but how could I use the information with no post?

Answer (score 0):

Well open Visual Studio Click File -> New -> Website -> Empty Web Site.

Create a `MasterPage.master` and add it to you project.

Example:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<html>
//.......
</html>
```

Create a `SearchPage.aspx` and bind it with your master page. Example:

```
< Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

Comment: I know it's been 6 years, but what do you mean by "bind"?

Answer (score 0):

don't add content to the master page (you can, but don't for this example), add it to the content-page (.aspx). having the form on the master page means you don't have to manually add a form to content-pages; it's there automatically. (everything on the master page will be on the content-page.)

as masood is showing, search.aspx (the content-page) is using a master page, MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master". content goes in the content-tag.